# Perl, Invoke new() inside package

Tags: perl

So, i have a perl module, and i want to use it not only as module, but standalone utility. Is it correct to call new() inside module like that:

```
package Module::Module;

sub new(){};

sub some_method(){};

sub _standalone_init(){
    $module = __PACKAGE__->new();
    #some magic and operations with $module' content
    &some_method();
};

__PACKAGE__->_standalone_init() unless caller;

1;
__END__
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `__PACKAGE__->class_method` is perfectly legit.

Lots of other problems, though:

- You are using incorrect prototypes.
- You are using prototypes.
- You are using prototypes on methods, even though they are ignored for method calls.
- `$module` should be scoped to the method in which it's used.
- You should use the provided class instead of `__PACKAGE__`.
- I'm not a fan of "modulinos" (`... unless caller;` at the top level of modules).
- You nave needless `;` terminating your sub declarations/definitions.

Fixed:

```
package Module::Module;

sub new { ... }

sub some_method { ... }

sub _standalone_init {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $object = $class->new();
    $object->some_method();
}

__PACKAGE__->_standalone_init() unless caller;

1;
```

or just

```
package Module::Module;

sub new { ... }

sub some_method { ... }

__PACKAGE__->new()->some_method() if !caller;

1;
```

Comment: Seems like the first edit is exactly what i need, because second ignores `#some magic and operations with $module' content`. Thank you, i'll try that.

Comment: 1) No, it didn't ignore. `some_method` is still called to do that. 2) You can still do extra stuff without the extra method that's not really a method at all. Poor separation of tasks in that first edit.